# A cousin of $\sum k\binom nk$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The goal is to find a closed form for
$$S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\min(k,n-k)\binom nk,\quad n\geq 0.$$
This question is from *Concrete Mathematics*.

The problem basically reduces to finding
$$R_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}k\binom nk,$$

since
$$S_n=2R_n+\mathbb 1_{\text{$n$ is even}}\cdot\binom{n}{n/2}\cdot\frac n2.$$

It is known how to find $R_n$ in case the sum went up to $n$ instead of $n/2$. Any clues on how to proceed here?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593747/42969