# Expectation that the last bin is empty (balls and bins questions)

Tags: probability, expectation, balls-in-bins

Say we have N balls and K bins. Let's call Y - The number of balls in the last bin. What is E(Y) ?

I don't know that way to get E(Y), I think there is a way of finding it without using indicators.

Comment: $$Y\sim B(N,1/K)$$

Comment: The question is just full on incomplete! (I guess everybody gets what you mean, but still it just looks hasty and incomplete)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expectaion of a balls and bins question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775494/expectaion-of-a-balls-and-bins-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that each ball is different (if they are the same, *make them different*).

The probability that one ball goes to the last bin is $\frac1K$.

Therefore, $Y\sim B\left(N,\frac1K\right)$.

Also, [the expected value of a binomial distribution with parameters $n$, $p$ is $np$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226237/expected-value-of-a-binomial-distribution).

Therefore, the expected value of $Y$ is $\frac NK$.